# Higher category theory (invertible morphism, Topological categories, monoidal n-category)

Tags: higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

I'm Looking at a paper using higher category theory. Would you please answer these questions ?

1) A weak n-category (or $\infty$-category) has objects and k-morphisms. What is an invertible morphism ?

2) What is the relation between topological categories (hom sets has topology and composition is continuous) and ($\infty$,1)-categories ?

3) I know what a symetric monoidal category is. Roughly speaking: what additional constraint/data do we have in a symetric monoidal n-category ($\infty$-category) ?

Comment: I answered the question as if it was in part a request for references. Perhaps the questioner would like to rephrase it in such a form?

Comment: Questions about hard definitions used to be accepted on math overflow. If the algebraic topology community is serious about welcoming folks in, then we need to be willing to teach them about $\infty$-categories. It's certainly not undergraduate level material. That said, I agree with the comment that this question is poorly worded. If it's edited to give a bit more justification for WHY the user wants these answers, then I'd vote to reopen, because I think such questions should be on topic at MO. As I recall (3) is highly non-trivial; certainly not appropriate for Math.SE

Comment: Also, regarding (2), there are many models for $(\infty,1)$-categories, including Quasi-categories, Segal spaces, Complete Segal spaces, etc. A good list is in the unicity paper of Barwick and Schommer-Pries. On the list, you'll find $Cat_{Top}$, the category of topologically enriched categories. So I guess one answer to (2) is that these notions are the same, up to set theoretic obstructions (you may need to use a locally presentable model for Top, e.g. $\Delta$-generated spaces)

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you said which paper you are reading and which model of infinity categories you a happiest with. My favorite is 'quasi-category' although it is not really the most general. I will use it.

Again you should be a bit more precise in your questions so my answers may not be 100% best possible, and the best thing is to look at, say, Joyal's notes or the n-Lab pages for more detail.

1) Usually an 'invertible morphism' means invertible up to something (a 'homotopy') at the next level.  A (1-) morphism $x$ is a 1-simplex in the quasi-category. It is invertible if there is another one forming a (2,1)-horn which fills with the $d_1$ face being degenerate. (Of course that would mean left or right invertible, but if you look at, for instance, Joyal's notes you will see how if $x$ has a right inverse and a left inverse then filling a (3,1)-horn gives that they are equivalent up to 'homotopy'.)

2) Look for the topological form of the homotopy coherent nerve. This can be found now in several books. (I could plug that by Kamps and Porter for one!) You can also look at Rainer Vogt's original work and then Cordier's paper from about 1980 to get from a topologically enriched category to a simplicially enriched one and then to a quasi-category. (It would need  a lot more space to give you details here.)

3) I will not attempt to answer this as I am not sure of the latest position but look at the n-Lab pages for a start.

Some of this material is available in my Menagerie notes (on the n-Lab). Note also the link given by Andrei Halanay in another answer. (Edit: I can give further / more detailed references if you wish for them.)

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1) and 3) (and many more) are fully answered in this [course](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/InfinityCategories.pdf) by Moritz Groth. Question number 2) seems a little unclear to me, but maybe you'll find an answer at ncatlab.org.